# Filter a slice into a vector

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```
enum Bar {
    Bar0,
    Bar1,
    Bar2
}

struct Foo {
    bar: Bar 
}
```

I have a function that takes a slice of Foos:

```
fn do_the_thing(foos: &[Foo]) { ... }
```

Part of the thing that needs to be done is to call another function on all elements of the slice that have the same value for "bar":

```
fn another_func(foos: &[Foo]) { ... }
```

I tried something like this:

```
fn do_the_thing(foos: &[Foo]) { 
    let bar0_foos = foos.iter().filter(|f| f.bar == Bar0 );

    another_func(&bar0_foos);
}
```

Tragically, I'm told that bar0_foos is  a `&std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<...>>`. I've also tried:

```
fn do_the_thing(foos: &[Foo]) { 
    let bar0_foos = foos.iter().filter(|f| f.bar == Bar0 ).collect();

    another_func(&bar0_foos);
}
```

Here, I'm told that `std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied.

So, what's the right way of doing this? Should I be taking something other than a slice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied.

Since `Iterator::collect` returns a generic type, the compiler uses type inferencing to figure out what that type must be. In this case, you are passing a reference to `bar0_foos` to a function that accepts a `&[Foo]`. By inference, that means that `bar0_foos` must be of the type `[Foo]`.

Since `[Foo]` is an unsized type, you cannot create a value of that type.

Normally, you specify what type of collection to collect into:

```
let bar0_foos: Vec<_> = // ...
```

Which provides this error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[Foo]`,
    found `&collections::vec::Vec<&Foo>`
(expected slice,
    found struct `collections::vec::Vec`) [E0308]
<anon>:10     another_func(&bar0_foos);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The error message is a tiny bit misleading here, as a `Vec<T>` can operate as a `&[T]`, so that's not the real problem. The contained type is the problem: you have a collection of `Vec<&Foo>` but need to pass a `&[Foo]`.

Logically, the error makes sense. Your function takes a chunk of memory that represents a **contiguous** range of `Foo`, but that's not what you have. By filtering, you have the possibility of non-contiguous data. Additionally, you have created a range of pointers to your real data.

How do you fix it?

1. If you control `another_func`, you can change it to take in `&[&Foo]`.
2. You could change it to be more generic

   ```
   fn another_func<F>(foos: &[F]) 
       where F: Borrow<Foo>
   ```
3. You could copy / clone the values and create a new vector. Then you would have a `Vec<Foo>` which can be passed in as a `&[Foo]`.
4. You could reorder the input slice to put all the appropriate `Foo`s together, and then take a subslice.